# Decimal places in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, decimal, precision

I am calculating percentages. One example is coming down to 38589/38400

So the percentage is 100*(38589/38400) which equals something like 100.4921875, but the result shows up as 100.

How can I get it to be displayed with x number of decimals?

Similarly, will the same work if i'd like 2 to be displayed as 2.000000?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can cast it to a specific data type, which preserves the data type as well as rounding to a certain precision

```
select cast(100*(38589/38400) as decimal(10,4))
```

FYI

```
select 100*(38589/38400)
# returns 100.4922, not 100 for me

select cast(2 as decimal(20,6))
# output : 2.000000
```

Answer (score 5):

With regards to your number formatting have you looked at the [format function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format):

```
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.123456, 4);
        -> '12,332.1235'
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.1,4);
        -> '12,332.1000'
mysql> SELECT FORMAT(12332.2,0);
        -> '12,332'
```

so to get 2.000000 from 2 do:

```
SELECT FORMAT(2,6);
```

Also, according to mySQL's documentation regarding division:

> In division performed with /, the
>   scale of the result when using two
>   exact-value operands is the scale of
>   the first operand plus the value of
>   the div_precision_increment system
>   variable (which is 4 by default). For
>   example, the result of the expression
>   5.05 / 0.014 has a scale of six decimal places (360.714286).
>
> These rules are applied for each
>   operation, such that nested
>   calculations imply the precision of
>   each component. Hence, (14620 /
>   9432456) / (24250 / 9432456), resolves
>   first to (0.0014) / (0.0026), with the
>   final result having 8 decimal places
>   (0.60288653).

This would lead me to agree with @Cyberwiki regarding the result you would see from your division.

Comment: Adding .0 not required in MySQL. Also, using FORMAT returns a VARCHAR type, not a numeric anymore.

Comment: Ahh ok, removed that part.  Will MySQL display trailing zeros for a numerical type?

Comment: Thanks @AbeMiessler for mentioning the `div_precision_increment` system variable, it solved my recent problem with decimal division.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert one of the types to floating point:

```
SELECT 100.0 * ((338589 * 1.0)/38400) ...
```

Comment: @Richard, thanks for the correction. I use Oracle and MS SQL Server. Should have noticed it was a MySQL question.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to the reason why the result shows 100 instead of 100.4921875 is maybe related to the type of the corresponding column assuming that you store the result in a table column. Make sure that the type of that column is Double.

If you'd like 2 to be displayed as 2.000000, just multiply it by 1.0 as follows:

```
(select (100*(38589/38400*1.0))
```

and the output will show: 100.49219